# PEMParser bouncy castle read certificate and private key from PEM

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle

I have created a PEMParser object to which I pass a PEM string containing chain certificate, encrypted private key etc.  Which is the way to retrieve the decrypted private key and the certificate X509? I have tried with :

```
pemParser.readObject()
```

I am able to get a x509CertificateHolder (how to get the certificate from it?) and at the second call an encrypted privatekey info.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your pem file has two entries first is cert and second is key.

another assumption is that key is of type pkcs8 and it is password protected.

first call to pemParser.readObject() is done with assumption that first entry in pem file is of x509 certificate

second call to pemParser.readObject() is done with assumption that second entry in pem file is of pkcs8 password protected key

variable certificate will contain the x509 certificate and variable finalKey will contain the private key

```
private void getCertAndKeyFromPemFile(String fileName, String keyPassword) throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(fileName));

    JcaX509CertificateConverter x509Converter = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    X509Certificate certificate =x509Converter.getCertificate((X509CertificateHolder) pemParser.readObject());

    PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = (PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) pemParser.readObject();

    InputDecryptorProvider decryptorProvider = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder().build(keyPassword.toCharArray());

    PrivateKey finalKey = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().getPrivateKey(privateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(decryptorProvider));

}
```